# How do I go to the next error (not next problem) in VS Code using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, the <kbd>F8</kbd> keyboard shortcut takes you to the next 'problem'. Problems can be errors, warnings, or info. I want to cycle through **only** the errors using a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The github issue provided by [@user](/users/11107541) has a link to an extension, [Go To Next Error](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.go-to-next-error), which looks promising in my testing.  You can make a keybinding like this (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+8",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "go-to-next-error.nextInFiles.error",
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

or if you want to override the existing `F8` try these:

```
{
  "key": "F8",
  "command": "-editor.action.marker.nextInFiles",
  "when": "editorFocus"
},
{
  "key": "F8",
  "command": "go-to-next-error.nextInFiles.error",
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

That uses the across files command: `go-to-next-error.nextInFiles.error`.  The `go-to-next-error.next.error` command would not jump to other files.

Available commands are

```
go-to-next-error.nextInFiles.error      Go to Next Problem in Files (Error)     
go-to-next-error.next.error             Go to Next Problem (Error)      
go-to-next-error.nextInFiles.warning    Go to Next Problem in Files (Error, Warning)        
go-to-next-error.next.warning           Go to Next Problem (Error, Warning)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible- at least- not in vanilla VS Code without a dedicated extension that does it.

See this feature-request issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo opened by [torkelrogstad](https://github.com/torkelrogstad): [Go to next error/warning/info #105795](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105795). Quoting from the issue ticket:

> I'd love a feature where I could go to the next error in the file I'm in, or in the entire project, but not the next warning/info marker. Currently I have these shortcuts available:
>
> - `editor.action.marker.next`
> - `editor.action.marker.nextInFiles`
> - `editor.action.marker.prev`
> - `editor.action.marker.prevInFiles`
>
> I think it'd make a lot of sense to expose similar shortcuts for going to the next error, or the next warning, or the next info, but as separate groups.
>
> Example use case: I have a spell checker and a linter enabled for my project. The linter produces both warnings and errors, and the spell checker produces info markers. I care mostly about linter errors and compiler errors, and when those are fixed I care about spelling errors.

It's currently not implemented. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

As [Mark](/users/836330) showed in [their answer](/a/75452168), in the discussion thread of the issue ticket I linked, there is the [`yy0931.go-to-next-error`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.go-to-next-error) extension that can be used for this <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.